# Dynamic binding to dynamic table component

Tags: jsp, jsf, woodstock

According to this [site](http://www.winstonprakash.com/articles/jsf/dynamic_table.htm), a DataSource has to be dropped  on to the designer for a dataprovider to be created. The table is then created dynamically and binded to the dataprovider.

However, if my web application serves as a GUI for users where user can create table from another page and view it at another. How can I display/bind the newly created table as there will be no dataprovider present?

I have manage to work on it slightly. However, I do not understand why is it that there is no value/data in my rowGroup?

ModificationPage.java

```
public class ModificationPage extends AbstractPageBean {
    @Override
    public void prerender() {
        try {
            tempRowSet.setDataSourceName("java:comp/env/jdbc/testDB_MySQL");
            tempRowSet.setCommand("SELECT * FROM " + this.tempTable.toString());
            tempRowSet.setTableName(this.tempTable.toString());

            tempDataProvider.setCachedRowSet(tempRowSet);
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ModificationPage.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    public void tableID_processValueChange(ValueChangeEvent vce) {
        // Reset the gridpanel so that only the selected table is displayed
        if (gridPanel2.getChildCount() > 1) {
            gridPanel2.getChildren().clear();
        }

        this.tempTable.append(vce.getNewValue());

        Table dynamicTable = new Table();
        dynamicTable.setId(tempTable.toString());
        dynamicTable.setTitle(tempTable.toString());
        dynamicTable.setPaginateButton(true);
        dynamicTable.setPaginationControls(true);

        // Create the Table Row group dynamically
        TableRowGroup rowGroup = new TableRowGroup();
        rowGroup.setId("rowGroup1");
        rowGroup.setSourceVar("currentRow");
        rowGroup.setValueBinding("sourceData", getApplication().
                createValueBinding("#{ModificationPage.tempDataProvider}"));
        rowGroup.setRows(5);

        // Add the table row group to the table as a child
        dynamicTable.getChildren().add(rowGroup);

        int test1 = rowGroup.getChildCount(); // returns 0, why?
        int test2 = rowGroup.getRowCount(); // returns 0, why?
        int test3 = rowGroup.getColumnCount(); // returns 0, why?

        for (int i = 0; i < rowGroup.getRowCount(); i++) {
            // Create the table column
            TableColumn tableColumn = new TableColumn();
            tableColumn.setId(tempRowSet.getColumnNames()[i]);
            tableColumn.setHeaderText(tempRowSet.getColumnNames()[i]);

            // Add the table Column to the table row group
            rowGroup.getChildren().add(tableColumn);

            // Create the Static text and set its value
            StaticText staticText = new StaticText();
            staticText.setValueBinding("text", getApplication().
                    createValueBinding("#{currentRow.value['borrowerID']}"));

            // Add the static text to the table column1
            tableColumn.getChildren().add(staticText);
        }

        gridPanel2.getChildren().add(0, dynamicTable);

    }

}
```

Thank you.

Comment: This is not a very good question. No code. You didn't even hint in your question that you're using woodstock. Woodstock is dead anyway

Comment: hi @kolossus, thanks for pointing that out to me. I am currently on an internship and it was a request by my supervisor. Hence, this web application has to be developed using Woodstock. There is no code because I have yet to code it out yet. I am currently still working on the creation of the table. The idea is that on another page, it should display the newly created table with its data. However, I am not sure how can one bind dataprovider to table during runtime.